# where the body of function uv_prepare_invoke, only find define in libuv

Tags: node.js, libuv

I read the `libuv` sourcecode and found these function declarations:

```
void uv_prepare_invoke(uv_loop_t* loop);
void uv_check_invoke(uv_loop_t* loop);
void uv_idle_invoke(uv_loop_t* loop);
```

Defined in [`internal.h`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/win/internal.h#L258-L260).

But I can't find the function bodies, why?

Comment: you found it where exactly they are defined?

Answer (score 1):

The function bodies are generated through a macro. See [this](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/ca107b7f17fdbede154f00b63952eb523b003a4b/src/win/loop-watcher.c#L107-L120).